# PHP Composer Issues

Tags: php, composer-php

It's been quite a while since I have done any heavy PHP development. I am trying to bring an older library up to date with `composer` and `namespaces` and am having a hard time fully understanding things.

Here is my `composer.json`

```
{
    "description": "MyClass",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyClass\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write some examples on how to use the updated library, but am having trouble getting my code to run. Here is my example file:

```
<?php

use MyClass;

$account_id = 123; // Replace with your account id
$public_key = '09876'; // Replace with your public key
$private_key = 'privkey'; // Replace with your private key
$klass = new MyClass($account_id, $public_key, $private_key);

echo $klass->myMethod();
```

Every time I run the above code I get the following error:

```
Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'MyClass' has no effect
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyClass' not found
```

Comment: Have you `require` the `autoload.php` which `composer` created ?

Comment: What's the exact name of that "MyClass"? Show us the `namespace` line and the `class` line at the minimum, and also add the path starting from the location of `composer.json` to the file containing that class.

Comment: @sven I got it working, but my question is if someone else chooses to use my php lib, should I remove the autoload.php require in my own project? Do others who use my lib have to use composer?

Comment: No you should not remove generated `autoload.php`, since composer registers a PSR-compliant autoloader for your folders. Leave it as it is. Or force your users to register PSR-4 autoloader to your directory manually.

Comment: Your comment "I got it working" is useless. *HOW did you get it working?*